# How find this $f(a,b)=\frac{1+a^2+ab+b^2}{a+b}$ domain

Tags: inequality

let $a,b$ are real numbers,and such
$$a+b>0$$

For the following function $f(a,b)$, find its range.

$$f(a,b)=\dfrac{1+a^2+ab+b^2}{a+b}$$

my try: let $$a+b=x>0,ab=y$$
then
$$f(a,b)=f(x,y)=\dfrac{1+x^2-y}{x}=x+\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{y}{x}$$
then I can't,Thank you very much

Comment: You're trying to find the domain of $f(a,b)$? Isn't that just the set of points for which the denominator $a+b$ is not zero, i.e. $\{(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2:a+b\ne 0\}$?

Comment: Yes,this problem is find this domain of the $f(a,b)$, but $a+b>0$

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to find the domain?

Comment: It should be range !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint: $x^2\ge 4y \implies \dfrac{y}{x} \le \dfrac{x}{4} \implies f \ge \dfrac{3x}{4}+ \dfrac{1}{x}$

BTW, it is the range.